Sending data to google sheets by using Arduino Uno R4 Wifi issue
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define SS_PIN 10 // RFID SS Pin
#define RST_PIN 9 // RFID RST Pin

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "mousa_5Ghz"; // Your WiFi SSID
const char* password = "***************"; // Your WiFi password

// Replace with your server URL
const char* serverUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyPeD6cVu1ond1pIno6_20T3UXPpUNDaR3Pf1vLsv1AQ6_6_AKw0xGeuwI2qx_XLjJY/exec"; 

// Create MFRC522 instance
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); 

// Define a structure for users
struct User {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String studentID;
};

// Define your users
User users[] = {
  {"F3D74CA8", "Alice", "003"},
  {"430D96A6", "Bob", "002"},
  // Add more users as needed
};

const int numUsers = sizeof(users) / sizeof(users[0]);

// URL-encode function to handle special characters in parameters
String urlencode(const String& str) {
    String encoded = "";
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c = str.charAt(i);
        if (isalnum(c) || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == '.' || c == '~') {
            encoded += c;
        } else {
            encoded += '%';
            encoded += String((int)c, HEX);
        }
    }
    return encoded;
}

bool sendUIDToServer(String uid, String name, String studentID) {
    Serial.print("Preparing to send UID: ");
    Serial.println(uid);

    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected. Reconnecting...");
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        int retries = 10;
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && retries > 0) {
            delay(1000);
            Serial.print(".");
            retries--;
        }
        if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            Serial.println("\nFailed to reconnect to WiFi.");
            return false;
        }
        Serial.println("\nReconnected to WiFi.");
    }

    WiFiClient client;

    if (client.connect("script.google.com", 443)) {
        String url = String(serverUrl) + "?studentID=" + urlencode(studentID) + "&name=" + urlencode(name);
        Serial.println("URL: " + url);

        // Send GET request
        client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                     "Host: script.google.com\r\n" +
                     "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

        // Wait for server's response
        unsigned long timeout = millis();
        while (client.connected() && millis() - timeout < 5000) {
            if (client.available()) {
                String response = client.readStringUntil('\n');
                Serial.println("Response: " + response);
                if (response.startsWith("HTTP/1.1 200")) {
                    Serial.println("Data sent successfully.");
                    client.stop();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (millis() - timeout >= 5000) {
            Serial.println("Server response timeout.");
        }

        client.stop();
        return false;
    } else {
        Serial.println("Connection to server failed.");
        return false;
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Starting setup...");
    SPI.begin();
    rfid.PCD_Init();
    Serial.println("RFID Reader Initialized.");

    // Connect to WiFi
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("\nConnected to WiFi.");
}

void loop() {
    // Look for a new RFID card
    if (!rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if (!rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    // Read the UID
    String uid = "";
    for (byte i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
        uid += String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
    }

    uid.toUpperCase(); // Convert to uppercase for consistency
    Serial.println("Scanned UID: " + uid);

    // Check if the UID is valid
    bool isValid = false;
    String name = "";
    String studentID = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++) {
        if (uid.equals(users[i].uid)) {
            isValid = true;
            name = users[i].name;
            studentID = users[i].studentID;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isValid) {
        Serial.println("Valid UID. Sending data...");
        if (sendUIDToServer(uid, name, studentID)) {
            Serial.println("UID sent successfully!");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Failed to send UID.");
        }
    } else {
        Serial.println("Invalid UID. Access Denied.");
    }

    // Halt RFID reading
    rfid.PICC_HaltA();
    rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}


This is my code and it's not sending data by swiping the Rfid card as expected.
I've tried to put the URL of the app script followed by the data on the browser and it worked, so the problem isn't from the app script code or the google sheet permissions so can any body help me with the code if there is any thing missing or need some adjustments

Have you tried using the POST method in your HTTP request? HTTP Methods

Is the webApp deployed to run as you and user anonymous?
